# FFMPEG not recognising -crf or -qp

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I am trying to make a losslessly encoded mp4 video out of png images.

I have a folder of images named `frame-%d.png`.

`ffmpeg -i frame-%d.png -framerate 30 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 output.mp4`

FFMPEG rejects crf and qp with the message:

```
ffmpeg -i frame-%d.png -framerate 30 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 output.mp4
ffmpeg version N-97327-g05039c1334 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      56. 42.102 / 56. 42.102
  libavcodec     58. 78.102 / 58. 78.102
  libavformat    58. 42.100 / 58. 42.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.101 /  7. 77.101
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
Unrecognized option 'crf'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Why is crf unavailable?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is crf unavailable?

Because you have a double `-`: `--crf`.

Remove one of them and the option will be recognised.

Comment: Thank you but I tried both. Neither work.

Comment: It worked here when reproducing, then fixing your issue. If it still doesn't work for you after trying the above, you could repost full, updated command line and logs.